# Cannot get Uname by golang

Tags: go, system-calls, uname

I'm using golang 1.4.2 on Mac

I want to use [Uname](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#Uname) to get some information, followings are my codes:

```
package main

import (
  "syscall"
)

func main() {
  utsname := syscall.Utsname{}
  syscall.Uname(&utsname)
}
```

But I got these errors:

```
# command-line-arguments
./main.go:8: undefined: syscall.Utsname
./main.go:9: undefined: syscall.Uname
```

Any went wrong?

Comment: It doesn't look like you're doing something wrong. Can you make sure your Go version is 1.4.2 by running `go version`?

Comment: check `go env` too, making sure GOARCH and GOOS are correct.

Comment: I got `go version go1.4.2 darwin/amd64` by `go version`

Comment: buy my `goroot` is `GOROOT="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4/libexec"`

Comment: I just used brew to upgrade to 1.4.2 .

Comment: my `goroot` is now GOROOT="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4.2/libexec" after opening a new terminal tab. But I still got the same errors

Answer (score 8):

**TL;DR** `Uname` and `Utsname` are not available for OSX.

The reason is because those functions are not defined for the operating system.

Reading the documentation for `syscall` this jumped at me:

> The details vary depending on the underlying system, and by default, godoc will display the syscall documentation for the current system. If you want godoc to display syscall documentation for another system, set $GOOS and $GOARCH to the desired system.

Running `godoc syscall` on my Mac yielded the `sycall` documentation which does not include the `Utsname` type nor the `Uname` function call.

However, running `GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 godoc syscall` actually shows the `Utsname` and `Uname`.

Also, note that the package itself is locked down in favor of OS specific packages

https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/ => https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys

Answer (score 1):

(Adding a more direct answer with exactly how I got past this problem)

Instead of importing `syscall`, I imported `golang.org/x/sys/unix`.

Then, the following code-block:

```
u := syscall.Utsname{}
syscall.Uname(&u)
```

is replaced by:

```
u := unix.Utsname{}
unix.Uname(&u)
```

NOTE! You need to call relevant functions for Windows.

Relevant contents of `git diff`:

```
-       "syscall"
+       "golang.org/x/sys/unix"

-       utsname := syscall.Utsname{}
-       syscall.Uname(&utsname)
+       utsname := unix.Utsname{}
+       unix.Uname(&utsname)
```